# Using another order when window function result is equal

Tags: postgresql

I'm using the window function rank at the following query:

```
select *, 
       rank() over(partition by challenge_id order by total_distance desc nulls last) as classification 
from user_challenges uc 
  left join users u on u.id = uc.user_id 
  left join profiles p on p.user_id = u.id 
where challenge_id = 'de26076b-88ac-466e-8878-89d589c48d1c' 
limit 10 offset 0
```

This query returns the users ranked by the total_distance reached but when two or more users has the total_distance equal instead of ordering by the total_distance I'd like to order by the name of the user. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please add some sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Can't you just add `name` to the order: `ORDER BY total_distance DESC NULLS LAST, name`